# Memory leak on page allocation with malloc

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

Consider the following C code, which creates 100,000 4KB-sized pages, then frees 99,999 pages and, finally, frees the last page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_PAGES 100000

int main() {
    void *pages[NUM_PAGES];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        pages[i] = malloc(4096);
    }

    printf("%d pages allocated.\n", NUM_PAGES);
    getchar();

    for(i=0; i<NUM_PAGES-1; i++) {
        free(pages[i]);
    }

    printf("%d pages freed.\n", NUM_PAGES-1);
    getchar();

    free(pages[NUM_PAGES-1]);

    printf("Last page freed.\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile it, run it and monitor the process' memory usage, you can see that the memory usage reaches about 400MB before the first `getchar` (when memory is allocated for 100,000 pages), then it keeps the same even after 99,999 pages are de-allocated (after the second `getchar`) and, finally, it drops to 1MB when the last page is de-allocated.

So, my question is why is this happening? Why is the entire memory returned to the OS only when all the pages are freed? Is there any page size or any page alignment which prevents this sort of thing to happen? I mean, is there any page size or alignment the makes any malloced page be entirely returned to the operating system when only one page gets freed?

Comment: It happens because the allocations are so small your C library uses `sbrk()` to dynamically resize its uninitialized data. It is sequential, so it can only be shrunk when the latest allocation is freed. If you increase the allocation size to say 131072 bytes (128k), `strace` shows it uses `mmap()` instead for the allocations, and each `free()` actually returns the allocation to the OS. So, use an allocation cache, and only ask/return larger chunks to the OS.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Man, you saved my life! Thank you very much for the comments above and below. That's exactly what I was expecting from the answers. If you had answered (not commented) this, I would have accepted your answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely implementation-dependent, but I believe that this has to do with how the memory allocator works.  Typically, when the memory manager needs more memory from the OS, it calls the `sbrk` function to request additional memory.  The typical implementation of this function is that the OS stores a pointer to the next free address in memory where the process can get space.  The memory grows like a stack, much in the same way that the call stack works.  For example, if you allocated five pages of memory, it might look like this:

```
 (existing memory) | Page 0 | Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 | Page 4 | (next free spot)
```

With this setup, if you free pages 0 - 4, the memory manager inside the program will mark them as free, like this:

```
 (existing memory) |                                   | Page 4 | (next free spot)
```

Since the OS is allocating memory in a stack-like fashion, it can't reclaim all this memory from the program until Page 4 is done being used.  Once you free the very last page, the process's memory will look like this:

```
 (existing memory) |                                              (next free spot)
```

And at this point the program's memory manager can return that huge amount of free space to the OS:

```
 (existing memory) | (next free spot)
```

In other words, because memory is allocated as a stack, until you deallocate the very last thing you've allocated, the OS can't reclaim any of the memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for answering! Very good explanation about memory allocation. But, I'd like to know whether you know any way to avoid stack-like memory allocation, I mean, allocation of individual pages which are deallocated individually.

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite You'll probably need OS-dependant calls to get/release memory from the OS directly. Under windows you use [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) and [VirtualFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892(v=vs.85).aspx). On unices, use [sbrk(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk). Note that you are warned to just use malloc/free and avoid sbrk.

Comment: On Linux, larger allocations use `mmap()`, not `sbrk()`. Memory-mapped allocations are returned to the OS immediately when `free()`d. On my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on x86-64 with 6GB of RAM, using embedded GNU C library 2.15-0ubuntu14, allocations of 131072 bytes or more `mmap()`ed. Therefore, suggesting to use `sbrk()` is utter bollocks. Better approach is to coalesce allocations into larger units. This approach should work fine on all OSes, BTW.

Comment: I suggest using `mmap` instead of `sbrk`

Comment: @NominalAnimal- My apologies... I didn't intend to suggest `sbrk` as a good implementation.  I was under the impression that this was how `malloc` might work and was intending to use that understanding to explain what was happening.  `mmap` is definitely a superior choice here.

Comment: @templatetypedef: No worries! `malloc()` implementations do vary, and I was actually quite surprised that even GNU C library still uses `sbrk()`. Anonymous private `mmap()`ed pages are cheap and easy to implement, so if you need a special allocator (slab-based, pool-based, etc.), just go for it!